Propagator for the linearized Schwarzian action
I am reading a paper arXiv:1606.01857. This paper expand the Schwarzian action (3.18) with a perturbation
$$
\tau=u+\epsilon(u).\tag{4.26}
$$
Then the linearized action becomes
$$
I=\frac{C}{2}\int du[\epsilon^{\prime\prime2}-\epsilon^{\prime2}].\tag{4.27}
$$
And my question is how to get the propagator $\langle\epsilon(u)\epsilon(0)\rangle$? In my mind, we already know the partition function of this system. In order to calculate the propagator, we need to identify the source for $\epsilon$. For this system, which quantity is the source for $\epsilon$? Another method is also welcomed.

Hm, that theory looks like it has a ghost instability due to the higher order derivative term. But if you wanted to compute the propagator you could do it in any standard way. The coupling to an external source $J$ should be $\epsilon J$, just add that term to $I$ and then apply your favorite method.


The linearized Schwarzian action is a quadratic Euclidean action$^1$
$$\begin{align} I[\epsilon]~=~&\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\!du~\left( \epsilon^{\prime\prime 2}-\epsilon^{\prime2}\right)\cr
~\stackrel{\text{IBP}}{=}\,&\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\!du~\epsilon~{\cal D}\epsilon\cr
~=~& \pi\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}n^2(n^2-1)\epsilon_n\epsilon_{-n},\end{align}\tag{4.27} $$
with periodic boundary conditions
$$ \epsilon(u)~=~\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\epsilon_ne^{inu}~=~\epsilon(u+2\pi),\qquad\epsilon_n^{\ast}~=~\epsilon_{-n},$$
has zero modes $n\in\{-1,0,1\}$ and
a differential operator
$${\cal D}~:=~\partial_u^4 + \partial_u^2.$$

The Greens function/2-pt function/propagator
$$ G(u)~=~\frac{1}{\hbar}\langle\epsilon(u)\epsilon(0)\rangle $$
satisfies
$$\begin{align} {\cal D}G(u)~=~&\delta(u+2\pi\mathbb{Z})-\frac{1+2\cos u}{2\pi}\cr
~=~&\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{|n|\geq 2}e^{inu}~=~\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 2}\cos nu,\end{align}$$
where the relevant Dirac distribution is the Dirac comb without the 3 zero mode teeth.

The Greens function is$^2$ [1,2]
$$\begin{align} 2\pi G(u)
~=~&\sum_{|n|\geq 2}\frac{e^{inu}}{n^2(n^2-1)}~=~2\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{\cos nu}{n^2(n^2-1)}\cr
~=~&2\sum_{n\geq 2}\left(\frac{1}{n^2-1}-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\cos nu\cr 
~=~&\sum_{n\geq 2}\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{2}{n^2}\right)\cos nu\cr
~=~&1+\frac{5}{2}\cos u+\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left(\frac{\cos(n+1)u-\cos(n-1)u}{n}-\frac{2\cos nu}{n^2}\right)\cr
~=~&1+\frac{5}{2}\cos u-2\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left(\frac{\sin u\sin nu}{n}+\frac{\cos nu}{n^2}\right)\cr
~\stackrel{|u|<2\pi}{=}&1+\frac{5}{2}\cos u-(\pi{\rm sgn}(u)-u)\sin u-\frac{(\pi-|u|)^2}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}
.\end{align}\tag{3.128/4.28}$$
In the last equality we used the Fourier series
$$\begin{align}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{\cos nu}{n^2}~\stackrel{|u|<2\pi}{=}&\frac{(\pi-|u|)^2}{4}-\frac{\pi^2}{12}
~=~\frac{u^2}{4}-\frac{\pi|u|}{2}+\frac{\pi^2}{6} 
\cr\quad\Downarrow~&\quad\cr\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{\sin nu}{n}~\stackrel{|u|<2\pi}{=}&\frac{\pi{\rm sgn}(u)-u}{2}\quad\text{saw tooth profile}.\end{align}$$


References:

J. Maldacena, D. Stanford & Z. Yang, Conformal symmetry and its breaking in 2D Nearly AdS space, arXiv:1606.01857; eq. (4.28).

J. Maldacena & D. Stanford, Comments on the SYK model, arXiv:1604.07818; eq. (3.128).

G. Sarosi, $AdS_2$ holography and the SYK model, arXiv:1711.08482; eq. (61).



$^1$ In the action (4.27) let us for simplicity set the normalization factor $C=1$. The propagator (3.128/4.28) should contain an overall normalization factor $C^{-1}$, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer here.
$^2$ Alternatively one may use the residue theorem [3]
$$\begin{align} 2\pi G(u)
~=~&\sum_{|n|\geq 2}\frac{e^{inu}}{n^2(n^2-1)}\cr
~=~&\sum_{|n|\geq 2}\oint_n\frac{ds}{2\pi i(s-n)}\frac{e^{isu}}{s^2(s^2-1)}\cr
~=~&\sum_{|n|\geq 2}\oint_n\frac{ds}{e^{2\pi is}-1}\frac{e^{isu}}{s^2(s^2-1)}\cr
\stackrel{0<u<2\pi}{=}&-\sum_{|n|\leq 1}\oint_n\frac{ds}{e^{2\pi is}-1}\frac{e^{isu}}{s^2(s^2-1)}\cr
~=~&\oint_0\frac{ds}{1-s^2}\frac{1+isu+\frac{(isu)^2}{2}+{\cal O}(s^3)}{2\pi is^3\left(1+\frac{2\pi i s}{2}+\frac{(2\pi i s)^2}{6}+{\cal O}(s^3)\right)} \cr
~-~&\sum_{\pm}\oint_{\pm 1}\underbrace{\frac{ds}{s^2}}_{=1+(s\pm 1)(s\mp 1)}\underbrace{\frac{1}{s\pm 1}}_{=\pm 2\left(1\pm\frac{s\mp 1}{2}\right)}\frac{e^{\pm i u}\left(1+iu(s\mp 1)+{\cal O}((s\mp 1)^2)\right)}{2\pi i(s\mp 1)^2 \left(1+\frac{2\pi i (s\mp 1)}{2}+{\cal O}((s\mp 1)^2)\right)} \cr
~=~&\oint_0\!ds\left(1+s^2+{\cal O}(s^4)\right)\frac{1+isu-\frac{(su)^2}{2}+{\cal O}(s^3)}{2\pi is^3}\left(1-\pi i s-\frac{(\pi s)^2}{3}+{\cal O}(s^3)\right) \cr
~+~&\sum_{\pm} \left(1+\frac{1}{4}\right)e^{\pm i u} -\sum_{\pm} \frac{1}{\pm 2}i(u-\pi)e^{\pm i u}\cr
~=~&\ldots.
\end{align}\tag{61}$$
